# Does the Scala 3 library have a Show typeclass that works with `derives`?

Tags: scala, typeclass, scala-3

In Scala 3 it is possible to get the compiler to derive instances of certain typeclasses using the `derives TC` syntax.

The documentation page here https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/derivation.html gives an example of deriving from typeclasses `Eq` `Ordering` and `Show`, saying that these typeclasses are "common examples".

1. Is `Show` in the library somewhere?
2. If not, is there a typeclass for pretty printing in the standard library?
3. Have I been spoiled by Haskell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I guess no. At least not so far. It's easy to define it yourself. And it's easy to define many custom flavors of it (for any necessary use case).
2. I guess no.
3. Probably you are :) As well as by [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/), [scalaz](https://scalaz.github.io) etc.

https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/show.html

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Show.scala